# uitableview scrolling is getting stuck when load image in uitableview cell ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, image, uitableview, ios9

i am getting image url from api. and i have to load that images in my uitableview cell. so when i scroll my tableview its getting slow and stucky.

so how can i scroll eazily and fast with loading image

here is my code:

```
let cell : seperatecell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("seperatecell") as! seperatecell

    let dic : NSDictionary = mylistarray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary
    cell.lbldate.text = dic["date"] as? String
    //  cell.lblsummary.text = dic["excerpt"] as? String
    cell.lbltitle.text = dic["title"] as? String



    //  print(dic["attachments"])

    let total = dic["attachments"]!.count

    if (total > 0)
    {
        let myarray : NSMutableArray = (dic["attachments"] as? NSMutableArray)!
        //print(myarray)
        let dic1 : NSDictionary = myarray.objectAtIndex(0) as! NSDictionary
        //print(dic1)
        var newimage : String = ""


        newimage = dic1["url"] as! String


        if let url = NSURL(string: newimage) {
            if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
                cell.image1.image = UIImage(data: data)
            }        
        }

    }
    else
    {
        print("nil")
    }


    viewparent.hidden = false
    EZLoadingActivity.hide()

    return cell
```

Comment: download the images on secondary thread. like SDWebImage library in Objective-C

Answer (score 1):

You need to load images asynchronously.

The easy way is to use a library to do it for you. You can look around github, otherwise this is the one I use: [KFSwiftImageLoader](https://github.com/kiavashfaisali/KFSwiftImageLoader)

Otherwise, you need to download the image in a background thread and then set the image in the main thread.